# How do I configure the default docker registry to be insecure?

Tags: docker

I have edited `/etc/docker/config` and added a `insecure-registry` flag to the OPTIONS for `registry-1.docker.io`. All well and good, I can now docker login to registry-1.docker.io, that is the default docker registry, using `docker login registry-1.docker.io`.

What I can't do (still get an x509 error) is *just* `docker login`.

Not exactly blocked but a tad frustrated. What further changes to the config file are required?

Docker 19.0